# Создание шаблонов

Tags: c++

Подскажите статьи, литературу, где можно почитать про шаблоны, а то читаю на intuit не могу в них разобраться. На пальцах пример пожалуйста:)
Преимущества вроде понимаю, а вот как писать не понимаю.
Спасибо!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот Вам пример. Думаю, понять можно, что к чему.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class x1, class x2, class x3> class param
{
    x1 punkt, fio;
    x2 number;
    x3 date;
    param *p;
public:
    param(){};
    param(x1 _punkt,x2 _number,x1 _fio,x3 _date):punkt(_punkt), number(_number),fio(_fio), date(_date){};
    void set_number(x2 x){number=x;};
    void set_fio(x1 x){fio=x;};
    void set_punkt(x1 x){punkt=x;};
    void set_date(x3 x){date=x;};
    x2 get_number(){return number;};
    x1 get_fio(){return fio;};
    x1 get_punkt(){return punkt;};
    x3 get_date(){return date;};
    void set_p(param *_p){p=_p;};
    param *get_p(){return p;};

};

template <class x1,class x2,class x3> class spisok
{
    param <x1, x2, x3> *now,*first;

public:
    void set_NULL(){now=0;first=0;};
    void add_new();
    void del();
    void find();
    void view_all();

};

template <class x1,class x2,class x3> void spisok<x1, x2, x3>::add_new()
{   
    param <x1, x2, x3> *p=new param<x1,x2,x3>;

    x1 punkt, fio;
    x2 number;
    x3 date;
    cout<<"Vvedite punkt:   ";
    cin>>punkt;
    p->set_punkt(punkt);

    cout<<"Vvedite nomer reisa: ";
    cin>>number;
    p->set_number(number);

    cout<<"Vvedite FIO: ";
    cin>>fio;
    p->set_fio(fio);

    cout<<"Vvedite daty:    ";
    cin>>date;
    p->set_date(date);

    if(now==NULL)
    {
        first=p;
        now=p;
        now->set_p(NULL);
    }
    else 
    {
        now->set_p(p);
        now=p;
        now->set_p(NULL);
    }

};

template <class x1,class x2,class x3> void spisok<x1, x2, x3>::del()
{
    x1 fio;
    cout<<"Enter FIO:   ";
    cin>>fio;
    param <x1, x2, x3> *p,*pl;

    p=first;
    pl=p;
    while(true)
    {

        if(p->get_fio()==fio)
        {
            if(p!=first)
                pl->set_p(p->get_p());
            else first=p->get_p();
            p=first;
            pl=p;

        }
        else
        {
            pl=p;

            if (p->get_p()!=NULL)
                p=p->get_p();
            else break;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Deleted"<<endl;
}

template <class x1,class x2,class x3> void spisok<x1, x2, x3>::find()
{
    x1 fio;
    cout<<"Enter FIO:   ";
    cin>>fio;
    param <x1, x2, x3> *p;

    p=first;

    while(true)
    {

        if(p->get_fio()==fio)
        {
            cout<<p->get_punkt()<<"    "<<p->get_number()<<"    "<<p->get_fio()<<"    "<<p->get_date()<<endl;
        }

        if (p->get_p()!=NULL)
            p=p->get_p();
        else break;
    }
}

template <class x1,class x2,class x3> void spisok<x1, x2, x3>::view_all()
{

    param <x1, x2, x3> *p;

    p=first;

    while(true)
    {

        cout<<p->get_punkt()<<"    "<<p->get_number()<<"    "<<p->get_fio()<<"    "<<p->get_date()<<endl;

        if (p->get_p()!=NULL)
            p=p->get_p();
        else break;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    spisok <string,int,string> a;
    a.set_NULL();
    cout<<"Novaya zayavka"<<endl;
    a.add_new();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Novaya zayavka"<<endl;
    a.add_new();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Novaya zayavka"<<endl;
    a.add_new();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Vse zayavki:"<<endl;
    a.view_all();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Poisk zayavki:"<<endl;
    a.find();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Ydalenie zayavki"<<endl;
    a.del();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Vse zayavki"<<endl;
    a.view_all();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вроде как ваш код перегружен логикой, не имеющей отношения к вопросу. К примеру, зачем вопрошающему код функции find?.. Думаю что это только запутает, ибо по сути эта куча кода иллюстрирует, наскока могу понять, не более чем работу с тройкой полей произвольного типа. В данном случае лучшим примером было бы дать ссылку на что-то вроде boost::tuple (столь же запутанно, но как-то пополезней и поприятней читать:) )

Comment: да желательно отредактировать))

Comment: rojaster, здесь были добавлены лишние символы ="" при описании шаблона.

Comment: Неплохо было бы комментарии к коду написать.

Comment: @Montreal, неплохо было бы посмотреть на дату ответа.

(при желании можно обнаружить, что его автор последний раз посещал ХК   12 Сен '13 10:14, а перед этим был аж 8 Дек '12 13:30)

Answer (score 4):

Если операции идентичны для каждого типа данных, более компактно и удобно использовать шаблоны функций (С++).

Программист пишет единственное определение шаблона функции. Основываясь на типах аргументов, указанных в вызовах, компилятор С++ автоматически генерирует разные функции для соответствующей обработки каждого типа.

Таким образом, определение единственного шаблона определяет целое семейство решений.

Определение шаблона начинается со слова template. Затем в угловых скобках следует список формальных типов параметров функции.

```
template <class T>
T maximum(T value1, T value2, T value3)
{ 
   T max = value1;
   if  (value2 > max)
           max = value2;
   if (value3 > max)
           max = value3;
   return max;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

По моему, испорченному, мнению, после прочтения книги "Плаугер, Степанов: STL - стандартная библиотека шаблонов С++" ISBN: 5-94157-437-1 все встанет на свои места, а заодно поближе с STL познакомитесь.

Comment: спасибо , воспользуюсь вашим советом )а то надоело с++ уровня университета, хочется что нить большее)))

Answer (score 1):

Например, "Шаблоны C++ Справочник разработчика" (Дэвид Вандевурд, Николаи М. Джосаттис), там есть описание всех тонкостей шаблонов от простого к сложному. Так же, чтобы поучиться шаблонной магии можно почитать "Современное проектирование на C++" (Андрей Александреску). Почитать исходники Boost, там всё на шаблонах. Стандарт, по необходимости. И тогда, с шаблонами будет всё понятно. То, как используются шаблоны в STL не полностью отражает их возможности, а только где-то половину, но ее будет хватать в большинстве случаев.

Comment: Это книги совершенно не для начинающих.